# Geometry with complex numbers.

Tags: complex-analysis, algebra-precalculus, complex-numbers

Let $a$, $b$, $c$, and $d$ be four complex numbers on the unit circle, such that the line joining $a$ and $b$ is perpendicular to the line joining $c$ and $d$.

[image]

Find a simple expression for $d$ in terms of $a$, $b$, and $c$.

I have thought of using power of a point, but that has gotten me nowhere so far.  Can anyone help me?

Comment: If you are having trouble seeing the picture, open it in another window.

Comment: $a-b = \pm \, i(c-d)?$

Comment: Very nice question! +1

Answer (score 10):

We want that 
$$\lambda:={d-c\over b-a}$$
is purely imaginary. This is equivalent with $\lambda=-\bar\lambda$, or
$${d-c\over b-a}=-{\bar d-\bar c\over\bar b-\bar a }=-{{1\over d}-{1\over c}\over{1\over b}-{1\over a}}\ .$$
This at once simplifies to $ab=-cd$.

Answer (score 1):

The angles corresponding to the arcs from $d$ to $a$ and from $c$ to $b$ add up to $180$ degrees.

That is,
$$\frac{ab}{dc}=-1$$

Comment: This doesn't seem to make much sense: "the angle from d to a" meaning $\;\angle BDA\;,\;\;\angle CDA\;$ , or what?

Comment: With the angle from $x$ to $y$ I mean the arc of the circle that starts at $x$ and ends at $y$.

Comment: @aj Isee...but then perhaps you should better call them "arcs

Comment: Vectors are introduced as  complex numbers back door... Dot product is a must. Argument difference $\pi/2$ useful only when rotation is around the origin.

Comment: I think that your end result is correct, but I don't see why these angles should add up to $180^\circ$. It's the opposite angles in a circular quadrilateral that add up to $180^\circ$.

Comment: @ChristianBlatter Join $c$ to $a$. We have $2(\angle DCA+\angle CAB)$ is the sum of the mentioned arcs, and indeed it is $2\cdot (180^{\circ}-90^{\circ})=180^{\circ}$.

Comment: Or use the fact that the angle between two chords (in this case, $90$ degrees) is half the sum of the two subtended arcs.

Answer (score 1):

Since $|a| = 1$, we have $a \overline{a} = |a|^2 = 1$, so $\overline{a} = 1/a$. Similarly, $\overline{b} = 1/b$, $\overline{c} = 1/c$, and $\overline{d} = 1/d$.

The line joining $a$ and $b$ is perpendicular to the line joining $c$ and $d$, so
$(b - a)(\overline{d} - \overline{c}) + (\overline{b} - \overline{a})(d - c) = 0,$
which becomes
\begin{align*}
(b - a) \left( \frac{1}{d} - \frac{1}{c} \right) + \left( \frac{1}{b} - \frac{1}{a} \right) (d - c) &= 0 \\
\Rightarrow \quad \frac{(b - a)(c - d)}{cd} + \frac{(a - b)(d - c)}{ab} &= 0 \\
\Rightarrow \quad (b - a)(c - d) \left( \frac{1}{cd} + \frac{1}{ab} \right) &= 0.
\end{align*}

Since $b \neq a$ and $c \neq d$, we may divide both sides by $(b - a)(c - d)$, to get
$\frac{1}{cd} + \frac{1}{ab} = 0.$
Solving for $d$, we find $d = \boxed{-ab/c}$.